# OpenClover not Running - Error

Tags: java, maven, clover

I am trying to integrate OpenClover into my project.
I have a Java based webapp and I use maven
I have setup the plugin as follows

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openclover</groupId>
            <artifactId>clover-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <targetPercentage>50%</targetPercentage>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When I run the following command

```
mvn clean test clover:aggregate clover:clover -Dsurefire.skip.tests=false;
```

I get this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.openclover:clover-maven-plugin:4.2.0:setup (default-cli) on project fcservices-web: Execution default-cli of goal org.openclover:clover-maven-plugin:4.2.0:setup failed: Unable to load the mojo 'setup' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.openclover:clover-maven-plugin:4.2.0': com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
[ERROR]
[ERROR] 1) No implementation for org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession was bound.
[ERROR] while locating com.atlassian.maven.plugin.clover.CloverSetupMojo
[ERROR] at ClassRealm[plugin>org.openclover:clover-maven-plugin:4.2.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@55f96302]
[ERROR] while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=org.openclover:clover-maven-plugin:4.2.0:setup)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] 1 error
[ERROR] role: org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo
[ERROR] roleHint: org.openclover:clover-maven-plugin:4.2.0:setup
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Any ideas what is up here?

Thank you
Damien

Comment: Are you using supported version of maven for this clover? Did you try older version?

Comment: Could you write which Maven version do you use? Furthermore, Maven reports it tries to execute _clover:setup_ goal, but you haven't configured it anywhere, not executed explicitly. Do you have some parent configuration your project might inherit where are OpenClover settings ? Could you update your question with those as well ?

Comment: @Hrabosch - I am using Maven version 3.0.5

Comment: @grzlew- i dont have anything configured in a parent pom. This worked previously on a different project without any mention of the setup goal in the pom

Comment: @Damien Ok, so it was wrong version. You can use newer maven or older clover version :) Up to you.

Comment: Hi. The OpenClover clover-maven-plugin version 4.2.0 has a bug and is incompatible with Maven 2.x and 3.0.x. The OpenClover 4.2.1 version has a fix for this. I encourage you to upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to the latest version of Maven (3.5.2) resolved this issue

Answer (score 1):

From error it looks like you need higher version of Maven or older version of Clover plugin.